# Arduino YUN Rest Api HTTP Post

Tags: arduino, iot, arduino-yun

I use `Arduino YUN` for `IoT` project.

I have a web service which requires headers and bodies, and I want to post data from `arduino`.

Default `HttpClient` library supports put, get and delete methods but doesn't support post method.

Any suggestion would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Process` class to send the `POST` via `curl` (which is a part of OpenWRT on Arduino YÚN).

Example from http://starter-kit.nettigo.eu/2014/arduino-yun-sending-data-thingspeak-post/:

```
void postToThingSpeak(String key, float value[]) {
  Process p;
  String cmd = "curl --data \"key="+key;
  for (int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++) {
    cmd = cmd + "&field"+ (i+1) + "=" + value[i];
  }
  cmd = cmd + "\" http://api.thingspeak.com/update";
  p.runShellCommand(cmd);
  Console.println(cmd);
  p.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an old version of the Bridge library. The code I am seeing in HttpClient.h supports POST (version 1.6.3):

```cpp
unsigned int get(String &url);
unsigned int get(const char * url);
void getAsynchronously(String &url);
void getAsynchronously(const char * url);
unsigned int post(String &url, String &data);
unsigned int post(const char * url, const char * data);
void postAsynchronously(String &url, String &data);
void postAsynchronously(const char * url, const char * data);
unsigned int patch(String &url, String &data);
unsigned int patch(const char * url, const char * data);
void patchAsynchronously(String &url, String &data);
void patchAsynchronously(const char * url, const char * data);
unsigned int put(String &url, String &data);
unsigned int put(const char * url, const char * data);
void putAsynchronously(String &url, String &data);
void putAsynchronously(const char * url, const char * data);
void setHeader(String &header);
void setHeader(const char * header);
boolean ready();
unsigned int getResult();
void noCheckSSL();
void checkSSL();
```